# Can I run a command in Laravel Tinker within just one entry in the CLI?

Tags: laravel, command-line-interface, tinker

I want to start using tinker to debug functions much faster. The issue is that for every change I need to stop and start tinker again.

I'm hoping I can use something like you have with mysql; you can start mysql and do your queries like that, but you can also run something like this
`mysql -u root -e "select * from users"`
which just works without starting up the mysql interface.

So I'm trying to find a way to do something like this

```
> tinker -e "User::find(1)->email"
"my.user@gmail.com"
>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use: **`php artisan tinker --execute="dump(User::find(1)->email)"`** which you can write a little bit shorter to be **`php artisan tinker --execute="dd(User::find(1)->email)"`**.

If you want to see more options, execute this: **`php artisan tinker -h`**. As you can see there, unfortunately there is no abbreviation for the `--execute[=EXECUTE]` flag.

Comment: tinker --execute="dump(User::find(1)->email)" works perfectly